# How to keep a button selected?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, avplayer

I am trying to create a loop button using AVPlayer. When the user taps a button (Loop) I would like it to stay selected until the user taps it again to unselect it. I have the following code but it does not seem to be working. Thanks!

```
@IBAction func didTapLoopButton(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let loopButton = sender as? UIButton else {
        return
    }

    if loopButton.state == .selected {
        print("selected")


    } else {
        print("deselected")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func didTapLoopButton(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let loopButton = sender as? UIButton else {
        return
    }

    let selected = !loopButton.isSelected

    if selected {
        print("selected")
    } else {
        print("deselected")
    }

    loopButton.isSelected = selected
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! How would I be able to execute code based if its selected or not selected? Kinda what I had above in my code

Answer (score 0):

combined from question and answer above:

```
@IBAction func didTapLoopButton(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let loopButton = sender as? UIButton else {
        return
    }

    loopButton.isSelected = !loopButton.isSelected

    if loopButton.state == .selected {
        print("selected")


    } else {
        print("deselected")
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that `loopButton.state == .selected` necessarily reflects `loopButton.isSelected`, and even if it does, you should always use `loopButton.isSelected` for the sake of consistency. I updated my answer with the code that I recommend using.